# Axes don't match array error in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I was trying to run the vnet implementation in pytorch
(https://github.com/mattmacy/vnet.pytorch) and after normalising the scans with

```
x_max = 512 
y_max = 512 
z_max = 500 
voxspacing = 0.7
```

when I call the `tran` function on the line where the for loop is enumerating through the data loader I get a

> axes don't match array error.

I don't understand how to fix this. Any help would be really helpful. I am a newbie in machine learning

Comment: what `tran` function? do you mean `train` or `transform` ? Also I couldnt find  `x_max`, `y_max`, `z_max` or even `voxspacing` that you are referring to.

Comment: in the train function. The x_max, y_max, z_max, voxspacing is in torchbiomed lib, in the datasets, in luna16.py file. it's used to make all the files to be of the same size and same padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment the lines 417 and 418. the issue will get fixed

the issue is because of these 2 lines

```
if self.transform is not None:
     img = self.transform(img)
```